# Incorrect logics

Tags: java, arrays, return, logic

So the point of this method is to get an array of temperatures above 100. What is wrong with this? When I return this in my toString it says blazing[] doesnt exist.

```
public int[] above100Degrees()
   {
      int[] blazing = new int[temps.length];
      for( int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++ )
      {
         if( temps[i] > 100 )
         {
            blazing[i] = temps[i];
         }
      }
      return blazing;
   }
```

toString method:

```
 public String toString()
    {
      String returnString = "The temperature forecast of week " + WEEK + " is logged in as: ";
      for( int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++ )
      {
          returnString += "\t" + temps[i] + "\t";
      }
      returnString += "\n" + "The number of temperatures below freezing is " + getUnderFreeze() + "." + "\n" + 
                             "The largest difference this week was a net change of " + NetChange() + "."; 
      for( int i = 0; i < blazing.length; i++ )
      {
         returnString += "The temperature above 100 degrees is " + above100Degrees() + "." + "\n" + "\t" + blazing[i] + "\t";
      }
      return returnString;
    }
```

Output

```
Forecast.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
      for( int i = 0; i < blazing.length; i++ )
                          ^
  symbol:   variable blazing
  location: class Forecast
Forecast.java:124: error: cannot find symbol
         returnString += "The temperature above 100 degrees is " + above100Degrees() + "." + "\n" + "\t" + blazing[i] + "\t";
                                                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable blazing
  location: class Forecast
2 errors
```

Comment: The array 'blazing' isn't declared in 'toString' method, and the array returned from 'above100Degrees' method isn't saved anywhere either.

Comment: ok so how do I use "blazing"'s elements, I want to display them

Comment: Looks like your variable `blazing` isn't available to your toString() method. From the code you posted above, `blazing` appears to belong only to the `above100degrees method`. You could make `blazing` a class level variable so it can be seen elsewhere

Comment: I'm assuming that you're pretty new to programming (or at least Java).  I think you'd benefit from using an IDE such as http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ .  It will highlight these sorts of problems for you amongst many another benefits.

Comment: You can't use `+` to put an array in a string.  Please look at [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[])).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change :

```
for( int i = 0; i < blazing.length; i++ )
{
    returnString += "The temperature above 100 degrees is " + above100Degrees() + "." + "\n" + "\t" + blazing[i] + "\t";
}
```

to :

```
int[] blazing = above100Degrees();
for( int i = 0; i < blazing.length; i++ )
{
    returnString += "The temperature above 100 degrees is " + blazing[i] + "."; // personalise format
}
```

Comment: What do I do about this hex code, it does not display the elements of the array

Comment: What does it display when you output to Sysout the result of the 'toString' method ?

Comment: Why do I have to set the array equal to the method?

Comment: Because the array 'blazing' in the method 'above100Degrees()' doesn't exist outside that method. To use it, it has to be assigned to another variable (in my example, the variable 'int[] blazing' in the 'toString' method; rgettman calls it 'reallyHot' in his example). If you don't assign it, it's lost.

Answer (score 5):

The array is returned by the `above100Degrees` method.  It does not establish the variable name `blazing` in the scope in which it's called.  In fact, you can assign the returned array to a variable named differently.

Try

```
int[] reallyHot = above100Degrees();
// Then check reallyHot...
for( int i = 0; i < reallyHot.length; i++ )
{
     returnString += "The temperature above 100 degrees is " + reallyHot[i] + "." + "\n";
}
```

Make sure to access the specific element with array access syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Your above100Degrees() function returns the array blazing but you don't invoke that function in your toString() method. As far as toString() is concerned blazing doesn't exist.

Call above100Degrees() from within toString() and save the resulting array to a variable. Then you'll be able to iterate over the (newVariable).length instead of blazing.length.